# Autoloading a class once class is called from an array using PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, autoloader

I have been looking through different frameworks and how they implement autoloading of their classes but I am new to PHP so am unsure whether I am interpreting its functions correctly. I have tried to create my own class only using it to autoload all my classes, the classes cannot be accessed. Here is what my code looks like:

```
class Autoloader {
    private $map = array();
    private $directories = array();

    public function register() {
        spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'load'));
    }
    public function unregister() {
        spl_autoload_unregister(array($this, 'load'));
    }
    public function map($files) {
        $this->map = array_merge($this->map, $files);
        $this->load($this->map);
    }
    public function directory($folder) {
        $this->directories = array_merge($this->directories, $folder);
    }
    public function load($class) {
        if ($file = $this->find($class)) {
            require $file;
        }
    }
    public function find($file) {
        foreach ($this->directories as $path) {
            if (file_exists($path . $file . '.php')) {
                return $path . $file . '.php';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I load the classes from my bootstrap file like so

```
require('classes/autoload.php');

$autoload = new Autoloader();
$autoload->map(array(
    'Config' => 'classes/config.php',
    'Sql' => 'classes/db.php'
));

$autoload->directory(array(
    'classes/'
));

$autoload->register();
```

Then I attempt to instantiate one of the classes that have been mapped

```
$sql = new SQL($dbinfo);
$sql->query($query);
```

What is wrong with what I have done and am I doing this correctly? I basically want the autoload class to map an array of classes from the bootstrap file and include the files when they have been called/instantiate and stop including them once they are no longer in use.

Comment: You are calling $autoload->map with an array as argument. map itself calls load with an array, which seems to expect a string?

Comment: Have you followed the code execution to see if it actually includes a class? Add some echo statements to see what happens

Comment: Also, try adding a debug echo / var_dump / die in your load function to see if spl_autoload_register actually causes your function to get called and echo out $file.

Comment: Where is it that you use `$this->map` again after `$this->map()`?

Answer (score 0):

Your classes seem to be called `Config`, your file `config` (notice case-sensitivity).

Guess file_exists fails for `"classes/Config.php"`.

You're not using your map at all at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem come from this line - `$this->map = array_merge($this->map, $files)` because you're passing `$files` to `$autoload->map()` as `Array`, but you're trying to get the value as `String` in `find()` method.

Comment: Okay so I've just tried altering the load class so that it just requires the merged array instead of finding the value as a string but it throws the error 'illegal offset type' and the function completely fails to grab the individual file so nothing can be included ('failed opening required'). The load function now looks like this:

`public function load($class) {
  if (isset($this->map[$class])) {
   require $this->map[$class];
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something strange going on with your "map" function.

When map is called it passes an array to load however the load function appears to expect $class which is used in the find function as if it was a string!

I think you need to have another look at how your calling your functions and keep track of what parameters are being used where.